# Почему при применении функции replace в С++ не получается заменить текст включающий в себя слэш?

Tags: c++, строки, replace

Почему если заменять куски текста, которые не включают в себя слэши, то функция replace работает, а если ты хочешь заменить что-то  вроде "\\devserver" из-за этих слэшей функция ничего не заменяет.

Вот пример нерабочего куска программы.

```
string Full_Path = f_Path[i] + f_Name[i] + ".cs";
int pos2 = Full_Path.find("\\");
    while (pos2 > 0)
    {
        Full_Path.replace(pos1, 16, "D:");
        pos2 = Full_Path.find("\\");
    }
    cout << endl << Full_Path;
```

Comment: @Harry да, прошу прощения за невнимательность!

Comment: в сторону: для манипулирования путей, вместо строк, [можно `path` из `<filesystem>` использовать](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)

Comment: @jfs, а где она есть, эта библиотека?

Comment: @ixSci если пройти по ссылке, то можно увидеть что библиотека в новом стандарте или отдельно как boost.filesystem

Comment: @jfs, этого стандарта ещё нет, а уж его имплементации и подавно. Насколько я помню, filesystem есть только в последней студии, правда не понятно насколько хорошо и полно сделана(сам не пробовал). Так что пока рано говорить про эту библиотеку, тем более советовать её.

Comment: @ixSci вы не правы.  boost.filesystem существует много лет, а то что эта библиотека была включена в стандарт только помогает.

Comment: @jfs, ключевоё слово тут boost. Вы бы тогда его и советовали, а не C++ filesystem, которого, по сути, ещё нет.

Comment: @ixSci бесполезное различие в данном случае. Я порекомендовал библиотеку, а не какую-то её конкретную версию. В зависимости от платформы, версии компилятора разные версии могут быть полезны.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы, наверное, неверно поняли управляющие последовательности с строковых литералах (escape-последовательности). Они начинаются с *обратной* косой черты `\`, так что ваша искомая подстрока `"//"` таковой и остается. Если вы хотите искать *один* символ `/`, то так и пишите - `"/"`, а если один `\` - то `"\\"`... Если хотите заменить `\dev` - то ищите `"\\dev"`, а если `/dev` - то `"/dev"`. И учтите, что в каждой операционной системе свои слеши в путях - если Windows и поймет прямой слеш, то вернет путь только с обратным, например...

Можете посмотреть об управляющих последовательностях, например, [здесь](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

И еще - проверка, найдена ли подстрока, выполняется не сравнением с 0, а сравнением с `string::npos`. Если у вас первый же символ искомый - вы получите как раз `0` - все индексы в C++ нумеруются с нуля.

Comment: а если мне нужно заменить "\\devserver\project" на "C:\", то каким образом это будет выглядеть?

Comment: @user200355 Ну так сначала `size_type pos = str.find("\\\\devserver\\project");` затем, если `pos != string::npos`, то `str.replace(pos,strlen(\\\\devserver\\project"),"C:\\");` - примерно так.

Comment: спасибо большое, получилось!

Comment: @user200355  http://ideone.com/Ld1VXJ

Comment: А ещё можно использовать сырые строковые литералы `R"(\\devserver\project)"` чтобы не плодить слешей.